# unable to load javascript in webview until refreshed

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, opentok, tokbox

i have an html file called **room.html.erb** which has some js code.when i click on a link it has to load the above page.but the page is loading correctly except js code.when i refresh it working fine.

code in **room.html.erb**

```
<script src="http://static.opentok.com/v2/js/opentok.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
var apiKey = xxxxxx;//my apikey
var sessionId ="<%=@group.sessionId%>" ;
var token = "<%=@opentok_token%>";
var session;
OT.setLogLevel(OT.DEBUG);

session = OT.initSession(apiKey,sessionId);

session.on
({
    streamCreated: function(event)
    {
        session.subscribe(event.stream,'subscribersDiv',{insertMode: 'append'});
    }
});

session.connect(token,function(error){
    if(error)
    {
        console.log(error.message);
    }
    else{
        session.publish('myPublisherDiv',{width: 320,height: 240});
    }
}); 

</script>
```

i couldn't able to figure it out why it is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wait until the DOM is loaded?

```
<script src="http://static.opentok.com/v2/js/opentok.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
    var apiKey = xxxxxx;//my apikey
    var sessionId ="<%=@group.sessionId%>" ;
    var token = "<%=@opentok_token%>";
    var session;
    OT.setLogLevel(OT.DEBUG);

    session = OT.initSession(apiKey,sessionId);

    session.on
    ({
        streamCreated: function(event)
        {
            session.subscribe(event.stream,'subscribersDiv',{insertMode: 'append'});
        }
    });

    session.connect(token,function(error){
        if(error)
        {
            console.log(error.message);
        }
        else{
            session.publish('myPublisherDiv',{width: 320,height: 240});
        }
    }); 
});
</script>
```

**another method**

add

```
<div id="myPublisherDiv"></div>
<div id="subscribersDiv"></div>
```